# Teradata Case Then Set Time Interval

Tags: case, teradata, intervals

I have a Teradata query where I subtract two TS fields to get the delta in minutes.

I then want to test another field using CASE, and return either the delta TS above or a defined interval.

However, I am getting a 7452: Invalid Interval error with the following code:

```
(TS2- TS1) day to minute as TS_DELTA,
        case when TIME_CATEGORY in('0-3 HOURS','3-8 HOURS')
        then TS_DELTA
        when TIME_CATEGORY = 'NEGATIVE'
        then interval '0' minute
        when GROUND_TIME = '> 8 HOURS'
        then interval '5' minute
        end as SUM_TIME
```

I have another CASE that defines TIME_CATEGORY, that works fine. I've narrowed down the error to the

```
then interval '5' minute
```

which I can't figure out what's going on. Any ideas?

Comment: You aren't showing the full calc, but I think your TS_Delta calculation is the problem.  Try `ts2 - ts1 minute(4)` as ts_delta`.  `day to minute` is not returning an actual minute interval.

Comment: Ok never mind the issue was MUCH stupider. I was testing the wrong field in my CASE statement. All good now (with your change) thanks!!